# jquery append lost after history back browser

Tags: jquery, browser, append

I have a form in which when a button is clicked, new inputs are appended.
Everything work correctly when submit, but if I hit the back browser all the appended fields are lost..

Is there a way to maintain them when hitting this browser's button?

thanks!

Comment: You have to use sessions or cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Your appended elements only exist in the DOM which isn't cached by any browser.

I suggest you use cookies to solve this issue, check out https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

To append something to such cookie

```
$.cookie("row", "a new row or whatever");

// or preferably a json
var myJsonRow = {
   row: 1,
   value: "Test"
}
$.cookie("row", JSON.stringify(myJsonRow));
```

To read this very simple cookie simply use

```
$.cookie("row");
```

Now obviously you will need something more advanced than this but this can be handled in the json object.

Start by creating a json pattern you feel comfortable with, something like this

```
// Basic row-pattern
var cookieRows = {
   rows: [
      {
         value: "row 1",
         type: "radio"
      },
      {
         value: "row 2",
         type: "text"
      },
      {
         value: "row 3",
         type: "password"
      },
   ]
}
```

And implement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Test if the cookie is set
   if(!$.cookie("rows")) {

      var cookieRows = {
         rows: []
      }

      // Register the pattern
      $.cookie("rows", JSON.stringify(cookieRows));
   }

   // Adding rows

   // Register your event handler
   $("#control").click(function(){

      // Get the control element
      var controlElement = $(this);

      // Fetch the needed information and create a row
      var cookieRow = {
         value: controlElement.val(),
         type: controlElement.attr('type')
      }

      // Get the cookie
      var cookieRows = JSON.parse($.cookie("rows"));

      // Add the value to the cookie
      cookieRows.rows.push(cookieRow);

      // And save the cookie
      $.cookie("rows", JSON.stringify(cookieRows));
   });
});
```

Ah well, you get the idea!

Comment: thank you both! I started testing with sessions, if i can't make it work i'll try with cookies instead.. bye!